# HTML images stacking up on each other not showing in a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem where images stacking up on each other not coming after each one. Even hiding the footer. I want to show the pictures in a grid layout where images coming after each one. For example 5 columns and every column contains 4 pictures.

Im new to HTML developing that's why I don't know what to do I reviewed my code thousands times but still can't figure it out.

Here's the issue:

[image: The problem]

```js
var gallery = document.querySelector('#gallery');
var getVal = function(elem, style) {
  return parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue(style));
};
var getHeight = function(item) {
  return item.querySelector('.content').getBoundingClientRect().height;
};
var resizeAll = function() {
  var altura = getVal(gallery, 'grid-auto-rows');
  var gap = getVal(gallery, 'grid-row-gap');
  gallery.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item').forEach(function(item) {
    var el = item;
    el.style.gridRowEnd = "span " + Math.ceil((getHeight(item) + gap) / (altura + gap));
  });
};
gallery.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(item) {
  item.classList.add('byebye');
  if (item.complete) {
    console.log(item.src);
  } else {
    item.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var altura = getVal(gallery, 'grid-auto-rows');
      var gap = getVal(gallery, 'grid-row-gap');
      var gitem = item.parentElement.parentElement;
      gitem.style.gridRowEnd = "span " + Math.ceil((getHeight(gitem) + gap) / (altura + gap));
      item.classList.remove('byebye');
    });
  }
});
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeAll);
gallery.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item').forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    item.classList.toggle('full');
  });
});
```

```css
.hello {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.full {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.full .content {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) !important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  position: inherit;
}

.full .content img {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  animation: zoomin 1s ease;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.byebye {
  opacity: 0;
}

.byebye:hover {
  transform: scale(0.2) !important;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 8px;
  grid-row-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 8px;
}

.gallery img {
  max-width: 80%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px #333;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.gallery img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px #333;
}

.gallery .content {
  padding: 4px;
  position: inherit;
}

.gallery .gallery-item {
  transition: grid-row-start 300ms linear;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery .gallery-item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.025);
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .gallery {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(30%, 1fr));
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .gallery {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(30%, 1fr));
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes zoomin {
  0% {
    max-width: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    filter: blur(4px);
  }
  30% {
    filter: blur(4px);
    transform: rotate(-80deg);
  }
  70% {
    max-width: 50%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    max-width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
  0% {
    max-width: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    filter: blur(4px);
  }
  30% {
    filter: blur(4px);
    transform: rotate(-80deg);
  }
  70% {
    max-width: 50%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    max-width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes zoomin {
  0% {
    max-width: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    filter: blur(4px);
  }
  30% {
    filter: blur(4px);
    transform: rotate(-80deg);
  }
  70% {
    max-width: 50%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    max-width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes zoomin {
  0% {
    max-width: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    filter: blur(4px);
  }
  30% {
    filter: blur(4px);
    transform: rotate(-80deg);
  }
  70% {
    max-width: 50%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    max-width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery" id="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <div class="content"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?tech,care" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <div class="content"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?tech,studied" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <div class="content"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?tech,studied" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <div class="content"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?tech,studied" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <div class="content"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?tech,studied" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <div class="content"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?tech,studied" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put the code in correct windows of single snippet so that your demo is runnable, right now it just prints a string

Comment: Edited and everything is in the correct windows.

Comment: They were all in 3 different snippets. I just to them together, looks like it works as expected. Try running it.